# Calling a javascript function from a link generated from a ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a javascript function. 
I'm making a AJAX call, and in that recieved content there is a link that I want to call the javascript function with.

```
MyJavascriptFunction(bla){
   alert (bla);
}

Result from ajax = "<a href="#" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction(bla)">Click</a>
```

Do I have to do anything special with the result from AJAX to get this to work or should it just work.

I have tried it like this but with no success with clicking the link.

The AJAX call:

```
function doSearch() {

  var form = $('form');

   $.ajax({
     url: "doSearch.php", 
     type: "GET",
     data: form.serialize(), 
     success: function(result){ 
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=result;
       }
    });
}
```

In the php I'm printing out

```
<a href="#" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction(bla)">Click</a>
```

Comment: have you tried it? That would tell you instantly if it works or not.

Comment: I realise I have not given enough info in my question. Yes, I have tried it. I have updated the post.

Comment: CHange <a href="#" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction(bla)">Click</a> for <a href="#" onclick="alert('test');">Click</a> and tell us if this shows a box when you click.

Comment: I tried with alert('test') and then I found out that the entire problem was how I concatinated the link with " and '. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try it. But yes you have to do something with the AJAX result. It has to be put somewhere in the DOM or the user won't be able to click on it.

Plus, make sure that the javascript function is a top level. I would suggest you use event handlers instead though.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have updated my question with some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<a>` tag to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction(bla); return false;">Click</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing jQuery and DOM. that is not pretty

try this - assuming you do not have more than one link in the html

```
success: function(result){ 
  $("#result").html(result).find("a").on("click",function() {
    MyJavascriptFunction(bla); 
    return false;
  };
}
```